# Pass data from angular form to another controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, model-binding

I am new to angularjs. I want to pass data from html form to another route.

Here is the part of **index.html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div ng-view=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the routes

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/', {
   templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
   controller: 'HomeController'
});
$routeProvider.when('/about', {
  templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
  controller: 'AboutController'
});
}]);
```

When the route  is **/** it hits the **views/home.html** in which it has a form

```
<form action="#/about" ng-submit="submitData()">
    <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="user.address" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I have a **user** service whose implementation is

```
myApp.factory("user", function () {
     return {};
});
```

I inject **user** service in **HomeController** like

```
 myApp.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, user) {
          $scope.user = user;
          // and then set values on the object

          // $scope.user.address = "1, Mars";    // when uncomment this line it can be accessed on AboutController? Why? Otherwise I cannot access user.address
          console.log($scope.user);
  });
```

Don note my comment in above code..

and passes **user** to AboutController like

```
myApp.controller("AboutController", function ($scope, user) {
    $scope.user = user;
    // and then set values on the object
    $scope.user.firstname = "John";
    $scope.user.secondname = "Smith";
    console.log($scope.user);
});
```

Here is the **about.html**

```
<p>
    {{ user.address }}
</p>
```

**Problem:** {{user.address}} doesn't work on **AboutController**. I can't see any output... But when i remove the comment from above code.. It only displays hardcoded values in the controller What am I missing?

This is the working demo [http://ashoo.com.au/angular/#/](http://ashoo.com.au/angular/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, all your service does is pass a blank object `return {}`, to any controller into which it is injected. You need a getter/setter approach, so that in your `Home` view you can set the data, and in your `About` view you can retrieve it.

So your service could look something like this:

```
myApp.factory("user", function () {

     var dataObj = {};

     return {
            setData: function(data) {
               dataObj.username = data.username;
            },
            getData: function() {
               return dataObj;
            }
     };
});
```

Now you can set the data in your `Home` controller:

```
myApp.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, user) {

    $scope.submitData = function(data)  {  //pass in ng-model
       user.setData(data);  //call 'user' service to set data
    }
  });
```

And call it from your `About` controller:

```
myApp.controller("AboutController", function ($scope, user) {
    $scope.user = user.getData();  //Assign 
    console.log($scope.user.username);
});
```

And you html would look like:

```
<form action="#/about" ng-submit="submitData(user.username)">
    <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="user.username" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome solution